# How do you solve the Tower level 48 puzzle?

Tags: guardian-tales

This is the puzzle that involves using bombs to progress forward.  In the 1st part you have to light a torch, hold a bomb, and walk the orange speed pads.  The torch lights the bomb you're holding and causes it to blow up at a specific time to destroy a rock.

I'm stuck in the 2nd part where you're supposed to use the bomb to flip a red/blue switch in a similar manner up above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this video:

If you look it up you will find other vids and articles on how to solve this level as well.
Hope this is helpful!